# iqengines demo app crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk, image-recognition

I'm trying to integrate iqengines sdk in my app(https://github.com/iqengines/iqe-android-sdk). i started with their demo app which i could not run properly.Installed Android NDK and Cygwin 1.7. also i have added the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT under eclipse substring and and modified API keys(https://github.com/iqengines/iqe-android-sdk#building-the-demo-app-). still the app crashes.
here is the stack trace.

```
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at com.iqengines.sdk.IQE.initIqSdk(IQE.java:249)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at com.iqengines.sdk.IQE.(IQE.java:224)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at com.iqengines.demo.DemoActivity.initIqSdk(DemoActivity.java:161)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at com.iqengines.demo.DemoActivity.onCreate(DemoActivity.java:133)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load iqindex: findLibrary returned null
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): at com.iqengines.sdk.IQLocal.(IQLocal.java:34)
04-08 14:32:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of the issues related to NDK and Windows 8. I switched to Ubuntu and it works fine.

Comment: Is there a link where these issues are explain? I have the same problem.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use NDK?

Comment: yes. NDK is needed for iqengine integration. check their github page.